# How can I make Matrix Multiplication Code run in parallel?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a block of code that takes user input and creates them into matrices but i need them to run in parallel as appose to running the code as one single process. I have no clue how to do so, i started reading into NumPy but haven't really grasped it.

```
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()

def getMatrix(name):
    matrixCreated = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        row = input('\nEnter elements in row %s of Matrix %s (separated by commas)\nOr -1 to exit: ' % (i, name))
        if row == '-1':
            break
        else:
            strList = row.split(',')
            matrixCreated.append(list(map(int, strList)))
return matrixCreated


def getColAsList(matrixToManipulate, col):
    myList = []
    numOfRows = len(matrixToManipulate)
    for i in range(numOfRows):
        myList.append(matrixToManipulate[i][col])
    return myList


def getCell(matrixA, matrixB, r, c):
    matrixBCol = getColAsList(matrixB, c)
    lenOfList = len(matrixBCol)
    productList = [matrixA[r][i] * matrixBCol[i] for i in range(lenOfList)]
    return sum(productList)


matrixA = getMatrix('A')
matrixB = getMatrix('B')

rowA = len(matrixA)
colA = len(matrixA[0])
rowB = len(matrixB)
colB = len(matrixB[0])

result = [[0 for p in range(colB)] for q in range(rowA)]

if (colA != rowB):
    print('The two matrices cannot be multiplied')
else:
    print('\nThe result is')
    for i in range(rowA):
        for j in range(colB):
            result[i][j] = getCell(matrixA, matrixB, i, j)
        print(result[i])

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

I also have a timer on the code to pint the time taken, but as its a programme that takes user input it is directly related to how long it takes to process in real-time, is there a way i can time it just to execute? I need to compare how making this code run in parallel can decrease run-time.

Answer (score 4):

`numpy` is an efficient C implementation, while `jax` is a an efficient parallel implementation that supports also GPU/TPU.

Both of then would run faster than your current `python` implementation.

Import `numpy` or `jax`

```
import numpy as np
```

or

```
import jax.numpy as np
```

Then create the matrices

```
A = np.array(getMatrix('A'))
B = np.array(getMatrix('B'))
```

And output the matrix multiplication

```
C = A @ B
print (C)
```

Comment: Nice answer providing a solution ! but not quite what was asked.. I would not dare to downvote, but I feel 780 wants to implement it in Python. I'm not a Python programmer, but I would guess the inside of your A @ B is what 780 APM is looking for. It would involve multiplying columns and rows for dot product in separate tasks (?)

Comment: How exactly would i implement this into my code? I can't seem to install NumPy either, i think I'm a little out of my depth lol.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the time of execution of the matrix multiplication than move the start after the user input, like this:

```
...
matrixA = getMatrix('A')
matrixB = getMatrix('B')

start = timeit.default_timer()    

rowA = len(matrixA)
colA = len(matrixA[0])
rowB = len(matrixB)
colB = len(matrixB[0])

...

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```